# morphline@flume - looking for regexp change and a hash function

Tags: solr, flume

Fluming data to Solr. Data get changed using morphline.

Looking for a couple of basic functions in morphline library:

1. create a hash value based on other attribute values (e.g. hash=("sha-1", timestamp,message,host,..)
2. change case of an attribute's string value (something more generic like regexp_replace would do as well).

Don't want yet to write a custom Java handler.. I think there is should be an easier way :)

Answer (score 0):

(1) Non-generic solution for hash function as I wasn't able to find out-of-the-box morphline implementation, hard-coded SHA-1 (eg. no for loop, hard-coded 20 bytes):

```
{       java {
            imports : "import java.security.*;"
            code: """
                try {
                    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1"); 
                    String value;

                    value = (String) record.getFirstValue("message");
                    if (value != null) { digest.update(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), 0, value.length()); }
                    value = (String) record.getFirstValue("timestamp");
                    if (value != null) { digest.update(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), 0, value.length()); }
                    value = (String) record.getFirstValue("hostname");
                    if (value != null) { digest.update(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), 0, value.length()); }

                    byte[] a = digest.digest();
                    record.replaceValues("id"
                        , String.format("%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X"
                            ,a[0]  ,a[1] ,a[2] ,a[3] ,a[4] ,a[5] ,a[6] ,a[7] ,a[8] ,a[9]    //SHA-1 has exactly 20 bytes
                            ,a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15],a[16],a[17],a[18],a[19]) );
                }
                catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { logger.error("hash to id: caught NoSuchAlgorithmException for SHA-1"); }
                catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e)   { logger.error("hash to id: caught UnsupportedEncodingException"); }
                finally {
                    return child.process(record);
                }
            """
        }
}
```

(2) Non-generic implementaion for lower case transformation (I would hope morphline had just something like regexp_replace) :

```
    java {
        code: """
            String program = (String) record.getFirstValue("program");
            String program_lc = program.toLowerCase();
            if (! program.equals(program_lc) )
            {   record.replaceValues("program", program_lc);        }
            return child.process(record);
        """
    }
```